# create superglobal variables in php?

Tags: php

is there a way to create my own custom superglobal variables like $_POST and $_GET?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Static class variables can be referenced globally, e.g.:

```
class myGlobals {

   static $myVariable;

}

function a() {

  print myGlobals::$myVariable;

}
```

Comment: You sir, made my day. But does it only work inside classes? Is there a way to do this outside a class?

Answer (score 37):

Yes, it is possible, but not with the so-called "core" PHP functionalities. You have to install an extension called [runkit7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit7.php):
[Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit7.installation.php)

After that, you can set your custom superglobals in php.ini as documented here:
[ini.runkit.superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit7.configuration.php#ini.runkit.superglobal)

Comment: This is the only answer on this question that actually answers it. The other ones are basically 'no, but you can do this instead'. +1, I wish it were higher.

Comment: For Swoole's HTTP Server, if we need to set Super Globals, runkit is also best use case there.

Answer (score 19):

I think you already have it - every variable you create in global space can be accessed using the `$GLOBALS` superglobal like this:

```php
// in global space
$myVar = "hello";

// inside a function
function foo() {
    echo $GLOBALS['myVar'];
}
```

Comment: What's the performance of using $GLOBALS array compared to simply using the variable itself?

Comment: ^ Same as any other nested array, it's essentially negligible. Having your own superglobal is appealing more for ease of use (less typing) and aesthetics.

Comment: $GLOBALS are not SUPERglobals!
Every global variable must be imported into a function scope using the `global` statement. Superglobals have no such limitation.

Comment: @Cláudio Silva $GLOBALS are super globals according to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) Accessing $GLOBALS inside a function does work.

Comment: What I meant was the variables accessible trough $GLOBALS are those that need to be imported explicitly via `global $varName` so they are not superglobals. Also, superglobal variables are not present on $GLOBALS. But the $GLOBALS array is, indeed, superglobal.

Answer (score 7):

```
   Class Registry {
 private $vars = array();
 public function __set($index, $value){$this->vars[$index] = $value;}
 public function __get($index){return $this->vars[$index];}
}
$registry = new Registry;

function _REGISTRY(){
    global $registry;
    return $registry;
}

_REGISTRY()->sampleArray=array(1,2,'red','white');

//_REGISTRY()->someOtherClassName = new className;
//_REGISTRY()->someOtherClassName->dosomething();

class sampleClass {
    public function sampleMethod(){
        print_r(_REGISTRY()->sampleArray); echo '<br/>';
        _REGISTRY()->sampleVar='value';
        echo _REGISTRY()->sampleVar.'<br/>';

    }
}

$whatever = new sampleClass;

$whatever->sampleMethod();
```

Comment: Adding a description to this answer would help people to understand what you have done.

Comment: This approach demonstrates the registry pattern and requires you to type `_REGISTRY()->` every time you want to access the variable for reading or writing.  The sampleClass is a demonstration of reading and writing to the registry from within the scope of a function. Personally I'm not a fan of the registry pattern, despite resorting to it often, but I do enjoy having a dedicated class, not intended to be constructed, where I can store a bunch of static variables, as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

One other way to get around this issue is to use a static class method or variable.

For example:

```
class myGlobals {

   public static $myVariable;

}
```

Then, in your functions you can simply refer to your global variable like this:

```
function Test()
{
 echo myGlobals::$myVariable;
}
```

Not as clean as some other languages, but at least you don't have to keep declaring it global all the time.

Answer (score 6):

**No**

There are only built-in superglobals listed in [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Answer (score 5):

Not really. though you can just abuse the ones that are there if you don't mind the ugliness of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Environment variables of the server, and access these in PHP
This is a good way to maybe store global database access if you own and exclusively use the server.

Comment: Note that this will only work for strings, and not complex data types like objects.

Answer (score 1):

possible workaround with **`$GLOBALS`**:

**file.php:**

```
$GLOBALS['xyz'] = "hello";
```

**any_included_file.php:**

```
echo $GLOBALS['xyz'];
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The point of a superglobal is that you can reference it without either `global` or `$GLOBALS`, so this is just two ways to access a normal  global.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create your superglobal variable in a separate php file and then auto load that file with every php call using the `auto_prepend_file` directive.

something like this should work after restarting your php server (your ini file location might be different):

**/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/load-my-custom-superglobals.ini**

```
auto_prepend_file=/var/www/html/superglobals.php
```

**/var/www/html/superglobals.php**

```php
<?php
  $_GLOBALS['_MY_SUPER_GLOBAL'] = 'example';
```

**/var/www/html/index.php**

```php
<?php
  echo $_MY_SUPER_GLOBAL;
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually, there is no direct way to define your own `superglobal` variables; But it's a trick that I always do to access simpler to my useful variables!

```
class _ {
    public static $VAR1;
    public static $VAR2;
    public static $VAR3;
}
```

Then I want to use:

```
function Test() {
    echo \_::$VAR2;
}
```

Notice: Don't forget to use `\` before, If you want to use it everywhere you have a `namespace` too...

Enjoy...