# Variables loaded from a separate script are not defined within functions

Tags: php

I use  settings.php  to store general settings for my application. When I load this settings file, I can use the variables defined in settings.php in the script itself, but not within any functions I define in it.

For example, in my class definition, myclass.php:

```
<?php 
$preIP = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once( "preIP/settings.php" );

class MyClass {
  ...
  public function foo() {
    echo $variable_from_settings;
  }
}
```

The code in the function foo() will not work (the variable will not be defined).

The settings.php file looks like this:

```
$variable_from_settings = "bar";
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting

```
global $variable_from_settings
```

before

```
echo $variable_from_settings;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following if you don't want to put `global $variable_from_settings;` everywhere.

```
echo $GLOBALS['variable_from_settings'];
```

However it's probably better to use a singleton to contain your settings as suggested in [create superglobal variables in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834491/create-superglobal-variables-in-php)