# Drupal 7 global $user variable

Tags: drupal

Would appreciate it, if anyone can let me know how we can set the `global $user` variable, so that we don't have to keep re-declaring it in each function, to access its contents.  How can we declare it so that all the functions in a module can use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of global you're looking for (available always, in every scope) is called a [superglobal](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in PHP. You cannot declare new superglobals, but you can access all globals directly because they are part of the `$GLOBAL` superglobal. In other words, you can use `$GLOBALS['user']` to access the $user global directly.

See also [create superglobal variables in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834491/create-superglobal-variables-in-php) for more info and alternative methods.

Comment: Thanks so much.  So now, I can just do $GLOBALS['user']->uid everytime I need to get the userid of the current user.

Answer (score 3):

You can't...that's how globals work in PHP. If you want to import the global variable into your local function then you have to use the `global` keyword, there's no way round it. This is a 'feature' of the PHP language, it has nothing to do with Drupal.

An alternative method might be to implement a helper function:

```
function get_current_user() {
  global $user;
  return $user;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$user = &get_current_user();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function if you want to use the $user variable, you just required to use/instantiate  'global' keyword before $user it. So that you can access all the data for that current user of the website.

For example

```
    function myGenericFunc(){
      global $user;
      $user_id = $user->uid;
    }
```

Note that you cannot redeclare it.

I hope it helps.