# PHP set a superglobal variable

Tags: php

The basis of the problem. I have a config file located at /random_folder/ranom_f/config/_config.php

I want to be able to access that file from /random/functions/php/functions.php

The config file  will not always be located in /random_folder/random_f/config/_config.php so I have to figure out a way to know where the config file is located.

My attempted solution is to set a superglobal (like in $_SERVER) that gives the "root" of the software I am creating.

Does anyone have a better solution / know how I can set a superglobal like that?

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers... but will I be able to access the myGlobals class from any file?

Answer (score 3):

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834491/create-superglobal-variables-in-php)

Static class variables can be referenced globally, e.g.:

```
class myGlobals {

   static $myVariable;

}

function a() {

  print myGlobals::$myVariable;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define a constant. Those are, by definition, superglobals (available to all scopes)

```
 define('FOO', 'some val');

 function yo() {
     echo FOO;
 }
```

The next best thing is simply using `$GLOBALS` (not recommended but also available to all scopes)

```
 $foo = 'some val';

 function yo() {
     echo $GLOBALS['foo'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a helper function. First of all i suppose that your config file path is relative to something, right?

The helper:

```
function get_config_path($params){
 /* code to select the path */
 return 'path'; /* path is a string */
}
```

In your main (index.php) file:

```
@include get_config_path($params).'/_config.php'; /* Add your standar config file name */
@include 'functions.php'

/* Use them */
```

That pretty much gives the main idea.

I hope it helps.