# Php the variable is available everywhere

Tags: php, variables

How can I do, that a variable will be available everything in raw PHP app?
I have variable $var in one file. In second file, which is included to first file, I have $var available, but if fhere is a class definition in second file, the variable is unavailable in that class. I need to do, the variable will be available everywhere, also inside class definition. Something similar like $_Session. His can I do that?

Comment: `$_SESSION`-type variables are called superglobals. While you can't create your own superglobals directly, you can mimic the behavior a bit. 1. Defining the variable in the global namespace and use the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword in other scopes. 2. Set up a static class with a public variable, [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834804/2453432).

Comment: I would actually like to ask the question "Why are you trying to achieve this?" There could be a much better way to achieve what you want, without polluting the global scope as this could lead to unintended consequences later on. So please elaborate a bit more on why you need to achieve this

Comment: I need to get mysqli connection sverywhere. I am remaking an ancient php app, which still uses mysql_pconnect. There is a pconnect and everywhere, where I write mysql_query, the app knows, that it should use this connection. In mysqli_query I need to link a mysqli connection, so I need a variable with mysqli connection and link it everywhere, also inside classes as well

Answer (score 0):

const of class and namespace?

const of class in different namespace can get different value even the name of the variables are same

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) to achieve this.

According to PHP manual,

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are
>   currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable
>   names are the keys of the array.

And the best thing, it is available in PHP 7 as well.

Comment: I will try this, thank you

Comment: WTF, even $GLOBALS doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `$GLOABALS`; You can also define constant by making use of `define`. ([refer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)) These constants are also accessible everywhere.

for e.g.

```
define('my_var', 'value_here');
```

to access this variable you can use;

```
echo my_var;
```

Comment: It should be noted though that these "variables" are indeed "constants". They cannot be changed in the course of the script.

Comment: Its a constant not variable